# Different navigation menu when user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble finding a way to create a different navigation menu when the user scrolls down. I am looking for something like this. http://www.kamellazaarfoundation.org

I want #small-menu to replace #big-menu when the user scrolls down.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/solxs9/d6ynfj1t/)

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="big-menu">
    <div id="big-logo">Big Logo</div>
    <div id="big-navigation">Navigation</div>
    <div id="big-search-bar">Search</div>
  </div>
  <!--<div id="small-menu"> ---Small Menu I want to replace the big menu with when user        scrolls down---
    <div id="small-logo">Small Logo</div>
    <div id="small-navigation">Navigation</div>
    <div id="small-search-bar">Search</div>
  </div>-->
<div id="content"></div>
</div>

#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
#big-menu {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#big-logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#big-navigation {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  float: left;
  margin: 70px 0 0 10px;
}
#big-search-bar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  float: right;
  margin: 70px 10px 0 0;
}
#small-menu {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid teal;
}
#small-logo {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#small-navigation {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
  float: left;
}
#small-search-bar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  float: right;
  margin: 30px 10px 0 0;
}
#content {
  height: 1200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

$(function() {
// Stick the #nav to the top of the window
var nav = $('#big-menu');
var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
var isFixed = false;
var $w = $(window);
$w.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
        nav.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: nav.offset().left,
            width: nav.width()
        });
        isFixed = true;
    }
    else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
    {
        nav.css({
            position: 'static'
        });
        isFixed = false;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This would be your jQuery code:**

```
var $document = $(document),
$element = $('.fixed-menu'),
className = 'hasScrolled';

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 100) {
    $element.addClass(className);
  } else {
    $element.removeClass(className);
  }
});
```

Here i set up a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6ynfj1t/1/) as example

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing large DOM replacements, consider using classNames and CSS instead, f.ex:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <div id="logo">Big Logo</div>
    <div id="navigation">Navigation</div>
    <div id="earch-bar">Search</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

And the JS, something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var isSmall = /* true/false; detect scrolling distance */;
  $('#menu').toggleClass('small', isSmall);
})
```

This will toggle the class `small` to the `#menu` container when a certain scrolling distance has been detected. The CSS could look something like:

```
#logo{height:100px} /* default (big) */
#menu.small #logo{height:60px} /* small */
```

These are just examples, you’ll need to figure out the implementation for your design yourself :)

Using CSS also gives you the benefit of doing fancy schmancy animations later on.